# What if my asked Question/problem solved by two different answers. Which one should I mark as accept?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

If I asked a Question and Got too many answers for that but Neither alone of them solved my problem but I got the solution by following two different answers which one should I mark as accepted.

What If we add an option of marking like solved partially, Or which one should I select.

**Edit**

Sometimes we get answers which will not solve the problem fully but solve the problem partially, This makes me thinking of an marking option of partially accepting an answer. It may have some problem or you may not be agree with it. Put your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think we need feature to mark answer as partial solution. Also, accepting an answer is solely based on OP. You don't have to accept both if they don't completely solve your issue, though you can upvote them for being helpful... or you can accept the one which is the most useful for you.

Comment: @AndrewT. I dont think this is a duplicate of above there the user asked for right way to self-answer If other answers assisted, but here I am asking for a feature of marking partially accepting an answer. Here you can go against me with proper reasons like (pros or cons) in your answer.

Comment: You can use the method as shown in the other question which was marked as dup. It's preferred that the accepted answer actually solves the problem fully when there is one.